# Noise Texture on Hair Mesh is Flowing the Wrong Way

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, hair

I'm not quite sure how else to word this, but I have a hair mesh with bangs that I'm trying to add a roughness map to. I'm making it from a noise texture, but the flow of the noise texture is not lining up with the flow of the bangs:
[image]
Right now, it's going this way:
[image]

I need it to flow this way:
[image]
I was thinking that trying to create some type of radial effect would help fix the issue, but I'm not familiar enough with math nodes to figure that out.
Here's my current node and UV layout if that would help give me answer:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried rotating the UVs of the mesh in the UV editor? Altenatively if you have the node wrangler add on enabled in the plugins under preferences you can select your shader and press CTRL+T to setup the auto UV mapping nodes, the mapping node has location, rotation and scale options you can edit, you've already got the two nodes it adds automatically in your setup. I notice however you don't have a shader in your nodes which normally goes before the material output.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I already tried that and to no avail. I have a shader that the noise would plug into, I just didn’t post it. Thanks for the tips though.

Comment: To avoid any unwanted distortion it might be better to model thinner sections of hair as separate meshes and just arrange and layer them, did you spherical map the UVs? Have you tried scaling the "bottom" of the bangs UVs wider in X than the top?